# how do i detect a multi-layered psd file using imageIO.framework?

Tags: cocoa, macos, javax.imageio, psd

i don't want to extract or use the multi-layer information, i want to report to the user that it can't be imported. i'm creating specific-sized jpgs from imported files, and the user needs to decide how to flatten that multiple-layered file according to her aesthetic.

the only reference to multilayered i see is `CGImageSourceGetCount(CGImageSourceRef)`

> If the image source is a multilayered PSD file, the function returns 1.

which, of course, isn't helpful in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own searching, you can't do this with ImageIO.  The *only* way I've found to deal with multi-layer images is with the QuickTime image importers.  See this link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImproveYourImage/Listings/Source_MultipleImages_c.html

Comment: thanks dale. your link led me to Quicktime's framework  `GraphicsImportGetImageCount()` method, which i am also seeing now is being used in Pixen's [source](http://opensword.org/pixen/download.php).